I'm confused with composite direction verbs, help me sort it out
I know the meanings of 出, 回, 来, 去, and similar direction verbs. However I have major issues understanding whenever they start combining with words like 上, 下, 前, 后, and so on.
The example: 王经理在三楼，你上去找他吧。
Why do we use 上去 here? What stops us from using, for example, 下去? The person may be in a higher floor of the same building. Can you explain me the logic behind the construction? Thanks.

All depends on the relative positions between you and the object
王经理在三楼，你上去找他吧。indicates your location is below where Manager  Wang is (you are either on the ground floor or the second floor and have to go up to find him)
王经理在三楼，你下去找他吧。indicates your location is above where Manager Wang is (you have to be on the fourth floor or above and have to go down to find him)
More examples:
王经理在外面，你出去找他吧 (if Manager Wang is outside, you have to go outside to find him)
王经理在里面，你进去找他吧 (if Manager Wang is inside, you have to go inside to find him)

What if the location of the speaker or the one they speak to is unknown?

then use 去 (go), e.g. 不知道王经理在哪里，你去找他吧

One minor point: the location isn't necessarily relative to you; it's sometimes relative to the person you're speaking to. In both English and Chinese, if you're on the phone with someone, you can say you will "come" over, and someone knocking at the door can ask if they can "come" in. In Japanese, it's strictly the speaker's position (i.e., "I'm going" not "I'm coming" when you're on your way).

Funny, that is the same in Spanish: Come here. Ven por acá. I'm coming! Ya voy. (literally: Already go.)

來 - come (towards me)
去 - go (away from me)
上 - on top; up.

上來 - coming up. 到屋顶上來 - coming up (to) the roof.

上去 - going up. 到屋顶上去 - going up (to) the roof.


下 - down lower; under.

下來 - coming down. 從屋顶上下來 - coming down (from) the roof.

下去 - going down. 用防火梯下去 - use the fire safety/escape stair going down.


出 - out

出來 - coming out. 你出來 - You, come out.

出去 - going out; get out. 出去走一走 - going out for a walk. 你出去 - You, get out.


回 - return

回來 - return/come back (to me). 別回來 - don't return/come back (to me).

回去 - return/go back (to him). 別回去 - don't return/go back (to him).



This is a very interesting question. It indeed has a logic behind those simple words. It depends not only on the position of the listener who is going to take the action as directed, but also on the position of the speaker who may be involved as the destination for the listener. For example,
(1) A and B are in different positions.
A: 我在一楼大厅。我去哪里找你？
B：我在二楼201房间。你上来吧。I am in the second floor. You come up to see me. (Towards me)
(2) A and B are talking face to face.
A: 我想见王经理。我去哪里找他？
B：他在二楼201房间。你上去吧。He is in the second floor. You go up to see him. (Going away from me)
